# Is Google Sheets capable of making a gantt-like chart like this? If so, how?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-charts-trendlines

I have two columns in a spreadsheet: A1:A100 has start times, and B1:B100 has duration. I am trying to create a chart that looks something like this, where each row gets a vertical line placed at the relevant start time (column A in the sheet) and the length of the vertical line is determined by the duration (column B in the sheet). Can it be done? I'm relatively new to this and I've tried column charts, waterfall, and scatter, but none seem to be working out very well.

[image: Gantt-like time chart with start times and durations]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19jW8OX1f10DG4ZxKSViF3-tk6SGeFsGRimEr22yqKpQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

not really, but it can be built (based on the sheet you provided):

**[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I6FqoyBd-cQO_l07PxlEDweGzQrucFW3iYQc5p7sxho/edit#gid=1252787081)**

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is pretty amazing. Do I understand this correctly? You basically create a formula which checks to see whether each cell should be colored or not based on the transposed sheet. Is that right? Pretty cool!

Comment: @PeterBentley yeah, pretty much yes :)